# Elementary os goes black when not touched for long

Tags: release-loki, power

When not touched for long elementary OS goes black with a small underscore at top left corner & when pressed any key pc doesn't wake up

Comment: Your pc probably went to sleep. See System Settings > Power for the relevant settings. Why it fails, could be caused by the driver of your graphics card. Could you share some details on your pc, Elementary version, graphics card info, selected driver.

Comment: @PeterUithoven I have 710M and I have installed GF117M from software & update (proprietary driver)

Comment: From a added ppa? And again, which Elementary OS version are you running?

Comment: @PeterUithoven yes via ppa. I am running Loki (latest) from website

Comment: And I confirm its graphic driver that's causing problem. Disabled it and moved to xorg default and not issue

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan if you were able to solve your own problem, can you write the answer below as an answer so other people will be able to reference it in the future? :)

Comment: I haven't yet solved the problem. It have just spotted it. Trying to fix it

Comment: Manually installing latest drivers from Nvidia website if that works

Comment: I'm not sure what 710M is, but if it's a Nvidia this page might be interesting: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia